# How to add results of multiple queries to an array in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Below is my code

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inbox ORDER BY `date` DESC ");
$stmt->execute(array());
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

$uniques = count(array_unique($row, SORT_REGULAR)); 

for ($i=0; $i < $uniques; $i++) {

    $inbox_id = $row[$i]["inbox_id"];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE inbox_id=? AND seen=? ORDER BY `date` DESC");
    $stmt->execute(array($inbox_id, 0));
    $row_msg = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                
}

return $row_msg;
```

But this is nor returning all data.It is only returning values got from first iteration only.

Comment: U mean: $row_msg [] ?

Comment: You're looping over each unique inbox result and then overwriting `$row_msg` every time. `$row_msg` should be a multidimensional array instead.

Comment: @bcmcfc yes it is a multidimensional array.Still i am getting undefined offset error in some messages fetched others are displayed normally.

Comment: Can you add the code which causes the undefined offset error?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BqCkrdXY

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
$row_msg[$i] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: do print_r($row_msg); and see what it has.

Comment: yes i did that and found multidimensional array.Still i am getting undefined offset error in some messages fetched.

Comment: then what is the problem.

Comment: Still i am getting undefined offset error in some messages fetched.

Comment: can you do this echo "<pre>"; print_r($row_msg);<echo "</pre>"; and paste because it is hard to read.

Comment: i don't see any undefined key.

Answer (score 0):

Your PDO statement is prepared every round inside the loop, that is not necessary and i hope the inbox_id column is a primary key in the inbox table:

```
$stmt1 = $db->query("SELECT `inbox_id` FROM inbox ORDER BY `date` DESC ");
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE inbox_id=? AND seen=0 ORDER BY `date` DESC");
while($id = $stmt1->fetchColumn(0)) {
    $stmt2->execute(array($id));
    $row_msg[$id] = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}    
return $row_msg;
```

If you do not want a multidimensional array you can just add the row to the result array by using array_merge() ([PHP Manual: array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)) inside the loop (instead of the line with $row_msg[$id]):

`$row_msg = array_merge($row_msg, $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

Comment: ok then how to change this code accordingly to echo messages.http://pastebin.com/BqCkrdXY

Comment: Outputting the messages is actually not part of the question. If you are not getting this right, you should first learn basic array operations and especially loops in PHP.

If multidimensional:
    foreach ($row_msg as $id => $msgs) {
        foreach ($msgs as $msg) { 
            echo $msg['msg'];
        }
    }
if not multidimansional:
    foreach ($row_msg as $msg) {
        echo $msg['msg'];
    }